# Imported JS script doesn't worked in ASP.NET view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In ASP.NET project trying to implement JS script work, but somehow it fails.
I've got my script in *Scripts* folder, JQuery import in *_ViewImports* and button in my *View*

I've also tried importing JQuery in *View* itself and wrapping script function into `$(document).ready(...)`, but neither helped.

Script functionality

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

JQuery import in *_ViewImports*

```html
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Using that functionality

```html
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/copyToClipboard.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard("default str")">Copy</button>
```

On page button is showing normally, but it don't do anything

Comment: Are you able to see script tag in the page?

Comment: see console to find query url and error info

Comment: In browser, press f12 and switch to source tab. Check whether the js file is shown under your application.

Comment: first problem solved: I didn't put my script to *wwwroot* so it wasn't connected to action, I do that now I can see it connects in my browser dev tools, but it still doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

_ViewImports file is not the correct place to register JavaScript. Try adding the jquery at the layout or in the partial view.

Comment: moved registrations to master layout, but result is still the same